# Can VMware ESXi host local storage as an iSCSI target to another device?

Tags: vmware, esxi, iscsi

Obviously in ESXi you can connect to an iSCSI target to access remote storage, but is there a way to host local server storage on an ESXi machine as an iSCSI target to another system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible. But you need 3rd party iSCSI Target Server running on top of ESXi. Neither ESXi nor commercial vSphere has built-in Target server. For vSphere clusters you can implement VMware vSAN, but I think it is not your case.

As iSCSI target server I can recommend [Starwind vsan](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san#VSAN-FREE), which besides providing local storage via iSCSI can also mirror it between hosts.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, but basically what I ended up doing was creating an additional VM running FreeNAS and sharing the target out that way. Seems like this should be something it can do out of the box, but I guess not.

Comment: ESXi is "compute" virtualisation platform and a "storage" aka SDS.